# Guidelines for attacking objects

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, objects

So in D&D 3.5, there were some suggestions for assigning AC and hit points to common objects, but in 5e we're left to speculate - the PHB has precious little, and I didn't see anything in the DMG. DM fiat is great, but I'd feel more comfortable with some kind of starting point, at least.

The one thing I saw today is that the Wall of Stone spell gives each panel AC 15 and 30 HP/inch of thickness.

So, question: What baseline examples or techniques do you use to judge the "combat stats" of inanimate objects like AC, HP, and resistance?

As per usual, good answers will be from official or semi-official sources, or from *personal experience* of having used them in a game and seeing how they played out in a 5e context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Basic Rules document has a section for [Statistics for Objects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/running-the-game#StatisticsforObjects), which is the same as the DMG, Chapter 8, Running the Game, Objects, Statistics for Objects, p246.  It provides suggested AC values for various substances.  It also gives guidelines for hit points.  For instance, a small fragile wood chest would be AC 15 and 1d6(3) HP.

Comment: So it does! Thanks, I missed that. I'll leave the question open for a bit in case anyone has any good expansions on that column.